# Mix-ide crashes on OS X El Capitan

Tags: mix

I freshly installed the entire Ehtereum toolchain on Mac OS X El Capitan. Everything works fine. However, I cannot launch the Mix IDE. It crashes on launch.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue? Wallet and command line tools run fine.

Here is the log:

```
Process:               Mix-ide [10124]
Path:                  /Applications/Mix-ide.app/Contents/MacOS/Mix-ide
Identifier:            .
Version:               ??? (mix )
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Mix-ide [10124]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-05-31 09:08:23.337 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        B3D9062B-8A56-4864-6CC8-5FB4218516FA

Sleep/Wake UUID:       66B83016-BC60-4E2A-BFAF-1AC3CCB96945

Time Awake Since Boot: 26000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        7  QThread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Answer (score 1):

We are working through this issue with Ralf on https://gitter.im/ethereum/mix right now.   Come and join us!